# Add thumbnail to material ui card

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I am using Material-UI card in my react we application. Currently the card is very plane, having title. I want to have a thumbnail on the left most side of card and next to that the tile of card, for example like a song list in some apps. I tried doing but I couldn't achieve. Is there any way to to add an image as thumbnail to the card(left most side). I want to match the thumbnail height to card height and thumbnail should start form left edge (no margin). Can someone help me?

Here is my code for current card:

```
render(){  
    return (
        <div>
            <MuiThemeProvider>
                <Card style= {{marginBottom: 2}} 
                      onTouchTap={() => {this.props.handleClick(this.props.id)}}
                      zDepth={this.state.shadow}>
                    <CardHeader
                      style={{fontFamily: 'Roboto, sans-serif', fontWeight:600}}
                        title={this.props.title}
                        //subtitle={value.description}
                        actAsExpander={false}
                        showExpandableButton={false}
                    />
                </Card>
            </MuiThemeProvider>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Could you try if `<CardHeader title="URL Avatar" avatar="images/ok-128.jpg" />` would work? Otherwise you'll need a custom CSS solution.

Comment: avatar will give me circle image

Comment: Set the `border-radius` of the avatar img to `0`, then it's square. You can also adjust the size and the paddings so it works for you.

Comment: can you please tell me how to set border-radius and padding of avatar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably better off creating your own component, or maybe using List/ListItem with a square image in your leftAvatar:

jsFiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/42f81uvv/1/

```
<List style={{ width: 400 }}>
  <ListItem
    innerDivStyle={{ paddingLeft: 80 }}
    leftAvatar={
      <img style={{ height: '100%', margin: -16 }} src="https://zartnerds.files.wordpress.com/2015/10/thumbnail.png" />
    }
    primaryText="Some Title"
    secondaryText="That's a good looking thumbnail"
    />
</List>
```